# How to best manage email address change with mutt

Tags: email, mutt

My institution is changing its name... and my professional e-mail is changing.

So far my `.muttrc` had:

```
alternates me@oldpro.com
alternates me@perso.com
set from=me@oldpro.com
set use_from
```

so that I replied to e-mails sent to my pro address with my pro address, and to personal e-mails with my personal address.

Now my new professional address is `me@pro.com`, I want to reply to *professional* e-mails with this, but not to personal. I of course update `set from`. If in addition I simply change my pro address in `alternates`, I have several drawbacks:

- E-mails I sent with my oldpro address are not recognized as sent by me anymore, so when listing folders I see they were sent by `me@oldpro.com`, not to whom I sent them.
- When replying to e-mails sent to several addresses including my `oldpro` address, this oldpro address get CCed.

Is there a better way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a configuration which does the required trick, as far as I could test so far. Following @Tony's advice, I keep my `oldpro` address in the `alternates` and am using a `send-hook` to rewrite it.

```
alternates me@oldpro.com
alternates me@pro.com
alternates me@perso.com
set from=me@pro.com
set use_from
send-hook . 'unmy_hdr From:'
send-hook '~f me@oldpro.com' 'my_hdr From: me@pro.com'
```

The first `send-hook` is needed since " if a hook changes configuration settings, these changes remain effective until the end of the current mutt session. As this is generally not desired, a default hook needs to be added before all other hooks to restore configuration defaults" according to Mutt user's manual — I don't think it very intuitive but so it is.

Answer (score 2):

**Use hooks.** You need to tell Mutt what is professional email and what is not.

If your professional recipients all use the @pro.com domain, and your personal contacts never use it, you could do:

```
alternates me@oldpro.com
alternates me@perso.com
set from=me@oldpro.com
set use_from

send-hook "~t '@pro.com$'" 'my_hdr From: John Smith <me@pro.com>'
```

Mail to all @pro.com recipients will use your professional mail. All the others would use the mail defined by `set from`.

If some of your contacts use the new @pro.com as personal mail, I am afraid you would have to add a `send-hook` line for each of these exceptions, per user basis.

You should keep as `alternates` all what is considered to be coming from you, even the addresses you are not using anymore.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Am I correct that this solution sets the From address according to the recipient? It is not convenient for me as I receive a lot of professional e-mails from many different domains. When replying to an e-mail, I'd like to select the From address according to the address that the recipient used to reach me.

Comment: Maybe you can suggest an improvement on my failed attempt with a `send-hook` following your answer, see my edit in the question.